# How can i get the current form which has the focus in infopath?

Tags: c#, infopath, infopath-2007

I have to get the currently focussed control in infopath. I only found "objects" via xmlPathNavigator, but with this i can not check if an element has the focus.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is ContextChanged event - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.infopath.formevents.contextchanged.aspx.
There is no direct access to controls in InfoPath.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not help me. It would if i can get the index of the element which i get by the contextChanged event (e.g. /Something[2]/myValue). I viewed the parameters and none of them (of the event) can give me the index.

Comment: event.Context gives you Xml node that is related to the change. If you need index - walk through all "Something" nodes and compare to context using IsTheSamePosition/IsDescendant (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator.aspx).